# How do I center a jQuery Coda-Slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, center, coda-slider

I am using Coda-slider as a jQuery slider plugin, and I am making a website for somebody. I ran past a problem:
http://texting2web.co.cc
Ignore the domain, I am waiting for my TLD to properly change to my new server :P

Anyways, as you can see the codaslider isnt centered. I have tried everything but nothing works. I also want the idicator dots on the bottom to be centered too. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 8 of slider.css says `float:left` for `.coda-slider`.

After removing that, you'll also want to add `margin:0 auto` for `.coda-slider`

As You figured out, giving the `ul` `text-align: center` centered the dots as well (also removing the `float:left`)

Comment: That works to center the box, but how do I center the dots aswell? I tried the same thing with the coda-nav but it didnt work

Comment: @Qasim Looks like you figured it out =) I'll add it to my answer for completeness

Answer (score 0):

Take `float: left` off of .coda-slider in your css

Also, to center the nav, you need to take the float off your `a`, and add `text-align: center` to your ul

Comment: When I do what you say for the nav, it turns into a vertical ul. have a look: http://texting2web.co.cc/

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this :

```
<div class="wrapper" align="center">
  <img src="<? echo "images/". $i .".jpg" ;?>" alt="temp"/>
</div>
```